# PHP - Resize image on upload AND keep original

Tags: php, image, laravel, upload, resize

I'm creating a site using Laravel 4, which allows an admin to upload a large number of images at a time. Currently, I'm able to do just that, where each image is given its own unique ID and put into its own folder named with the same ID.

The problem is that I need the application to also upload a second, resized (smaller) version of the image along with the original. I learned that you must resize an image on the client side, so I'm not sure how I would go about saving the original image, as well as smaller version. The smaller image should be named using the same ID, with some sort of identifier like "-smaller" at the end of the name.

Here's my current front end;

```
    {{ Form::open(array('url' => 'imageUpload', 'files' => true, 'method' => 'post'))}}

                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="fileToUpload" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Choose All Images</label>
                    </br>
                      {{ Form::file('images[]', ['multiple' => true]) }}
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                      {{ Form::submit('Add Photos', ['class' => 'btn btn-large btn-primary openbutton'])}}
                      <!--<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Sign in</button> -->
                    </div>

{{ Form::close() }}
```

And here's my controller;

```
    $files = Input::file('images');

    foreach($files as $file) {
        $rules = array(
           'file' => 'required|mimes:png,gif,jpeg,txt,pdf,doc,rtf|max:9999999999'
        );
        $validator = \Validator::make(array('file'=> $file), $rules);
        if($validator->passes()){

            $id = Str::random(14);
            $id = $race . "-" . $id;

            $destinationPath = 'raceImages/' . $id;
            //$filename = $id;
            $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
            $mime_type = $file->getMimeType();
            $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $upload_success = $file->move($destinationPath, $id);


            );
        } else {
            return Redirect::back()->with('error', 'I only accept images.');
        }
    }
```

Comment: why dont you have the server resize the image ?

Comment: That's what I'd like to do, but I've only seen resizing done in the front-end. How would resize on the server side?

Comment: Have you had a look at imagemagick library? See http://php.net/manual/fr/book.imagick.php, esp. http://php.net/manual/fr/imagick.resizeimage.php or http://php.net/manual/fr/imagick.adaptiveresizeimage.php

Comment: You can check out Intervention: http://image.intervention.io/

Answer (score 0):

This is how I resolved the same problem in my app:

1. Install this package: https://github.com/Intervention/image
2. Use this code:

   ```
   $createnew = new Yourmodelname;
    $avatar = Input::file('pic_path');
   if (isset($avatar)) { //will process the code only if an image was properly pointed in the form
   $image = Input::file('pic_path');
   var_dump($image->getRealPath()); // just for error tracking
   $filename = $image->getClientOriginalName();
   if (Image::make($image->getRealPath())->save('foldername/yourprefix_' . $LastInsertId . '_' . $filename)) {      } // foldername is related to your public folder
   if (Image::make($image->getRealPath())->widen(200)->save('foldername/thumbs/thumb_yourprefix_' . $LastInsertId . '_' . $filename)) {

   }

   $createnew->pic_path = 'event_poster_' . $LastInsertId . '_' . $filename;
   $createnew->pic_thumb = 'event_poster_thumb_' . $LastInsertId . '_' . $filename;
   $createnew->save();
   ```

   }

Now you have two files: one original (no changes) and a thumbnail scaled proportionally to width 280.
Other resize options you can find in the Intervention docs.